# Making a pandas dataFrame based on some column values of another dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame df1 with the following content:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C                            9
   C              12            13
   C              12
```

I would like to make a DataFrame that is based on `df1` but that has any row containing an empty value removed. For example:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C              12            13
```

I tried something like this

```
df1=df[~np.isnan(df["year"]) or ~np.isnan(df["current"])]
```

But I received the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `dropna` to achieve this:

```
df1 = df.dropna()
```

As to why what you tried failed `or` operator doesn't understand what it should do when comparing array like structures as it is ambiguous if 1 or more elements meet the boolean criteria, you should use the bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `~` for `and`, `or` and `not` repsectively. Additionally for multiple conditions you need to wrap the conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence.

```
In [4]:
df.dropna()

Out[4]:
  Serial N  year  current
0        B    10       14
1        B    10       16
2        B    11       10
4        B    11       15
5        C    12       11
7        C    12       13
```

Comment: Or `df1 = df.dropna()`

Answer (score 2):

Please try with bitwise operator `|` instead, like this:

```
df1=df[ (~np.isnan(df["year"])) | (~np.isnan(df["current"]))]
```

Using `dropna()`, as suggested by EdChum, is likely the cleanest and neatest solution here. You can read more about this or working with missing data generally [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#dropping-axis-labels-with-missing-data-dropna)

Answer (score 2):

if you really have empty cells instead of NaN's:

```
In [122]: df
Out[122]:
  Serial_N  year current
0        B  10.0    14.0
1        B  10.0    16.0
2        B  11.0    10.0
3        B  11.0
4        B  11.0    15.0
5        C  12.0    11.0
6        C           9.0
7        C  12.0    13.0
8        C  12.0

In [123]: a.replace('', np.nan).dropna()
Out[123]:
  Serial_N  year current
0        B  10.0    14.0
1        B  10.0    16.0
2        B  11.0    10.0
4        B  11.0    15.0
5        C  12.0    11.0
7        C  12.0    13.0
```